# How to get Parent term of a children term in woocommerce product attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Location(attribute)

```
--India(term)
---Mumbai ( term with parent of India)
---Kolkata ( term with parent of India)
```

In product attribute section I select `Mumbai` as location.

I can get this in product archive page as:

```
$product->get_attribute("pa_location");
```

But how can I get `India` (Parent of `Mumbai`) from `$product`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$product_id = 76;
//$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$product_location = $product->get_attribute("pa_location");//'Mumbai'
$parent_term_obj = get_term_by('name', $product_location, 'pa_location');
if ($parent_term_obj->parent != 0)
{
    $parent_term_obj = get_term($parent_term_obj->parent, 'pa_location');
}
//print_r($parent_term_obj);
```

Hope this helps!